# How can I wait the multiple setXXX for useState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have script like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData1("test"); 
    setData2("test2");
    initialize();
},[]);

const initialize = () =>{
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data2);
}
```

With this script, `data1` and `data2` are not set in `initialize()`;

So I want to wait until both `setData1` and `setData2` finished and then call `initialize()`

How can I make it?

Comment: setState is async so you cant assume it has run

Comment: You need to `useEffect` to see the result of the state changing, but that might well be triggered twice. It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, without context it's hard to say what the right solution would be.

Comment: How about you combine multiple states into a single tuple state? You will be able to set them both at the same time

Comment: If you use an effect to set state(s), you can only use those values in the subsequent render. If it doesn't make sense to run `initialize` on every render, you may want to put that in an effect itself so it runs whenever the data changes. If that doesn't make sense either, you should either not use an effect to setup your states with constant values in the first place, or you should just pass those values directly to `initialize` before setting the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `useEffect` that runs when `data1` or `data2` changes, then use an `if` if the data is what you'd expect

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [data1, setData1] = useState();
    const [data2, setData2] = useState();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setData1("test"); 
        setData2("test2");
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data1 && data2) {
            initialize();
        }
    }, [ data1, data2 ]);

    const initialize = () =>{
        console.log(data1);
        console.log(data2);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <p>{'Data1: '}<code>{data1}</code></p>
            <p>{'Data2: '}<code>{data2}</code></p>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: THank you very much ,I understood there is the no way like promise to wait the useEffect, So, this is the best practice for my case.